# Why the Generated ImageUrl is wrong

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, imageurl

i have strored images in  a folder within my project with name like this

```
(ProductID).Extention
```

and other details of image are stored in the database

i have used the following procedure to fetch the image

```
create proc prcMainPhoto(@ProductID int)
as 
select p.ProductID ,
isnull(( select top 1 convert(varchar,PhotoID,10) + '.' + ExtName from ProductPhoto where ProductID= p.ProductID ),'NoImage.jpg')as MainPhoto
from ProductInfo as p where p.ProductID=@ProductID
```

and give imageurl to image like this

```
DataSet ds1 = new ClientProductView().GetMainPhotoInDeatailPage(productid);
string img = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MainPhoto"].ToString();
imgmain.ImageUrl ="./productimages / main / "+ img;
```

but the image is genrating this url

```
http://localhost:1030/SShopping%20Website/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID=1#
```

i have coded in page ProductDetails which is placed outside

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must give imageurl like this

```
 DataSet ds1 = new ClientProductView().GetMainPhotoInDeatailPage(1);
        string img = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MainPhoto"].ToString();
        image.ImageUrl = string.Format("productimages/main/" + img);
```

Comment: so does that mean that the ./ before the image path was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue here is that [ImageUrl can only be assigned with either a relative or an absolute URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx). I think that the use of . in your URL path is that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image url with a relative path:

```
imgmain.ImageUrl ="~/productimages/main/" + img;
```

Comment: How do you define imgmain? Can you post a bit more of the code please